# Creating HTML element depending on existing element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page can be several <select> with HTML structure like this:

```
<select name="test" id="test" class="custom">
    <option value="test 1.1">test 1.1</option>
    <option value="test 1.2">test 1.2</option>
    <option value="test 1.3">test 1.3</option>
</select>

<select name="test2" id="test2" class="custom">
    <option value="test 2.1">test 2.1</option>
    <option value="test 2.2">test 2.2</option>
    <option value="test 2.3">test 2.3</option>
</select>
```

And .selectBox structure like this:

```
<div class="selectBox">
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="selectArrow">&#9660;</span>
    <div class="selectOptions">
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Option 1</span>
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Option 2</span>
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Option 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

With help of jQuery I want to make for each <select> on the page with class custom own .selectBox with data from this <select>. Option's values and text from <select> should be in <span> with class selectOption. How can I better do this?

Comment: Question is not clear.. Please explain

Comment: You might very well use a plugin like Select2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is jquery multiple select

Answer (score 0):

The question is not super clear but I think you want to get the options from the select with id `test2` for example and replace the options of your custom select `.selectBox` with them.

Add to it an id like `selectBox2` to refer it to the select `test2`.

```js
var selectOptions = [];
    
$('#test2 option').each(function() {
    selectOptions.push($(this).val());
});
        
$('#selectBox2 .selectOption').each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).attr("value", selectOptions[i]);
    $(this).html(selectOptions[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="test2" id="test2" class="custom">
    <option value="test 2.1">test 2.1</option>
    <option value="test 2.2">test 2.2</option>
    <option value="test 2.3">test 2.3</option>
</select>

<div class="selectBox" id="selectBox2">
    <span class="selected"></span>
    <span class="selectArrow">&#9660;</span>
    <div class="selectOptions">
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Option 1</span>
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Option 2</span>
        <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Option 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give it a try!

Btw: you should definitely have a look at -> https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/